# Python: im trying to write a text file but it just keeps getting cleared

Tags: python

I have been searching for a while but i cant find anything. I'm trying to save whatever i type to a text file with the line number next to it but right after something gets put on the text file, everything in the file just disappears. I'm pretty new to python so i don't know too much.

Main code:

```
import time, sys, random, os
RR = open("import.txt","r")
Read = RR.read()
new = open("import.txt","a")
edt = open("import.txt","w")
linenum = len(open("import.txt").readlines(  ))
prefix = (str(linenum)+"- ")
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
    lines[line_num] = text
    edt.writelines(lines)
    edt.close()
RR.close()
print(Read)
print("What would you like to do?\n")
print("\nNew|Reload|Edit\n")
ask = input()
if ask == "New":
    print("Please enter your text.\n")
    pen = input()
    new.write(str(prefix)+(pen))
    new.close()
    print("\n\033[1;32m Complete\033[0m \n")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('clear')
    exec(open("Reload.py").read())

elif ask == "new":
    print("Please enter your text.\n")
    pen = input()
    new.write(str(prefix)+(pen))
    new.close()
    print("\n\033[1;32m Complete\033[0m \n")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('clear')
    exec(open("Reload.py").read())
elif ask == "Edit":
    print("What line would you like to edit?\n")
    num = input("Line number: ")
    print("Please enter your text.\n")
    pen = input()
    replace_line("import.txt", (num), (str(prefix)+(pen)))
    new.close()
    print("\n\033[1;32m Complete\033[0m \n")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('clear')
    exec(open("Reload.py").read())
elif ask == "Reload":
    exec(open("Reload.py").read())
```

Reload code:

```
import time, sys, random, os
print("Please Wait.")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('clear')
time.sleep(1)
exec(open("main.py").read())
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself.

Comment: don't forget to close file after writing. If you want append new text to existing one then you have to open in `append` mode - `open(..., "a")` - because `write` mode (`open(..., 'w')`) removes previous content

Comment: always put code in question as text, not link to external portal.

Comment: it makes no sense to open the same file 4 times - it can make only conflict. One `open()` will try to append at the end when other will try to write from start and it will delete other text.

Comment: to execute code many times use `while True:` loop instead of `exec()`

Comment: i put the code in the question

Comment: as I said before - `open(..., 'w')` automatically delete previous content. I don't know why you open `edt = open("import.txt","w")` if you don't even use it later. And it deletes conent.

Comment: Why are you using `open`/`read`/`exec` instead of importing a module that defines a function that you can call repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're not supposed to open the same file multiple times, if you want to be able to read and write you can merge the two parameters "r" and "w" into "rw" for example.

Second, you can make use of the operator OR when you check your input, like:

```py
if ask == "New" or ask == "new":
```

or

```
if ask.lower() == 'new':
```

Using the above "if" condition will make it case insensitive.

I noticed you used a code to call your main code. You're not supposed to do that either, in these cases where we wanna keep on doing things we use a while loop. Like this:

```py
while input() != "nothing":

       #put your code here
```

This will keep your code on asking what you wanna do until you type "nothing".

Close your file object only in the end of your code, since opening them costs quite a lot if your file is considerably big or/and you keep on doing this on a loop.